# list containing first weekday of every month in numbers 0-6 using the calendar module

Tags: python, module, calendar

Currently trying to obtain a list of the first week day of every month starting Monday as 0 to Sunday as 6. The printed result should be indicated like this e.g.
for year 2020 [2, 5, 4, 0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6, 1]

With the current script after inputting current year 2020 and January's first weekday 'wednesday' I get

TypeError:unsupported operand type(s) for %:'NoneType'and'int'

Here is the current script that i have, any insight or help is greatly apreciated!

```
import calendar


yr_input = input("Today's year: ")
yr= int(yr_input)


first_week_day_input = input('Enter the first week day of January: ')

def jan_1st_wd(x):
    
    if first_week_day_input.lower() == 'monday':
        fst_wd = 0
    elif first_week_day_input.lower() == 'tuesday':
        fst_wd = 1
    elif first_week_day_input.lower()== 'wednesday':
        fst_wd = 2
    elif first_week_day_input.lower() == 'thursday':
        fst_wd = 3
    elif first_week_day_input.lower() == 'friday':
        fst_wd = 4
    elif first_week_day_input.lower() == 'saturday':
        fst_wd = 5
    elif first_week_day_input.lower() == 'sunday':
        fst_wd = 6
    
        return fst_wd

fst_wd = jan_1st_wd(first_week_day_input)   

wd_list=[]

cal = calendar.Calendar(firstweekday=fst_wd)

y=1

yr= int(yr_input)


def first_wdL(yr , jan = 1):
    
    
    y=1

    while y < 13:

        for x in cal.itermonthdays2(yr, jan):
            if x[0] == 1:
                wd_list.append(x[1])
                continue
        jan+=1      
        y += 1  
        
wd_list = first_wdL(yr) 

print(wd_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're complicating things. Using `datetime()` with a loop:

```
from datetime import datetime
year = 2020
week = 1

result = []
for i in range(1,12):
    result.append(datetime(year, i, week).weekday())
print(result)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[2, 5, 6, 2, 4, 0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6]
```

**EDIT**:

one-liner:

```
print([datetime(year, i, week).weekday() for i in range(1,12)])
```